# Using instagram API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, policy

i need to use instagram api public_content scope to
get the recent media liked by the user.

and this is use case and permissions compliance

> We will approve submissions of apps that fall into these use cases:
>
> ```
> 1-To help individuals share their own content with 3rd party apps
> 2-To help brands and advertisers understand and manage their audience and digital media rights
> 3-To help broadcasters and publishers discover content, get digital rights to media, and share media with proper attribution
> ```

my qusetion is what they mean by brands , advertisers,broadcasters and publishers ?
and i  need some examples of applications that compatible with these conditions to use the api

Answer (score 1):

A publisher is anyone who is publishing content, like a blogger.